# Proof for property of proportionality used in deriving physical laws like law of gravitation and coulombs law

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, dimensional-analysis, coulombs-law, models

$$\text{F} \propto m_1m_2$$
$$\text{F} \propto \frac{1}{r^2}$$

Therefore $$\text{F} \propto \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$

In physics one quantity $\text{F}$ is directly proportional to two other quantities ($m_1m_2$ and $\displaystyle \frac{1}{r^2}$), then the product of the last two quantities is directly proportional to the first quantity $$\text{F} \propto \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$$

This property intuitively makes sense but I have never seen a rigorous proof of it or ever seen it being formally written in a textbook.

Can someone please prove it rigorously.

(The law of gravitation is simply the most popular application of the problem I have asked. I do not want to know the inner workings of the law of gravitation. I only want to know the how proportionality can be combined. But if further understanding of law of gravitation is required then I am open to it.)

Comment: Are you familiar with Gauss's law?  Ultimately laws like this are deeply intertwined with the conservation of quantities.  (Mass, in the case of newtonian gravity, charge in the case of electromagnetisim).  There is a lot of deep math that is intertwined with this that would easily take a chapter of a textbook to explain from scratch.

Comment: What exactly you do not understand from the answers given in the math SE post?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer I haven’t studied it yet but we are going to study it in class in a few months

Comment: @Jakob don’t understand how k=f(C) or k′=g(B) in the other question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It boils down to what $\propto$ (proportional to) means.
When we say
$$F(m_1,m_2,r) \propto m_1m_2$$
this means
$$F(m_1,m_2,r) = A(r)m_1m_2 \tag{1}$$
with some unknown function $A$.

Likewise, saying
$$F(m_1,m_2,r) \propto \frac{1}{r^2}$$
means
$$F(m_1,m_2,r) = B(m_1,m_2) \frac{1}{r^2} \tag{2}$$
with some unknown function $B$.

Now the only way to satisfy both (1) and (2) simultaneously is
$$F(m_1,m_2,r)=Cm_1m_2 \frac{1}{r^2}$$
with some unknown constant $C$, or
$$F(m_1,m_2,r) \propto \frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}.$$